# Google login in redirect loop using HybridAuth

Tags: php, laravel, google-signin, hybridauth

I am using atticmedia/anvard package in laravel for social login. Login for the facebook works fine, but when I login using google, it stays in a redirect loop. The google login page is successfully shown and when i have given access it redirects back to `http://domain.com/endpoint?hauth.done=Google&code=XXXX#`

I have no idea why is this not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to enable Google+ and Contacts API in the APIs google console. Wandered two days and this was the issue. I feel so stupid. But seems like this information isnt mentioned much in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

## Basic steps

Protocol Flow

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 | Client |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+

                 Figure 1: Abstract Protocol Flow
```

The abstract OAuth 2.0 flow illustrated in Figure 1 describes the
   interaction between the four roles and includes the following steps:

(A)  The client requests authorization from the resource owner.  The
        authorization request can be made directly to the resource owner
        (as shown), or preferably indirectly via the authorization
        server as an intermediary.

(B)  The client receives an authorization grant, which is a
        credential representing the resource owner's authorization,
        expressed using one of four grant types defined in this
        specification or using an extension grant type.  The
        authorization grant type depends on the method used by the
        client to request authorization and the types supported by the
        authorization server.

(C)  The client requests an access token by authenticating with the
        authorization server and presenting the authorization grant.

(D)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
        the authorization grant, and if valid, issues an access token.

(E)  The client requests the protected resource from the resource
        server and authenticates by presenting the access token.

(F)  The resource server validates the access token, and if valid,
        serves the request.

## Answer

You must have redirected the user to authorisation and after authroisation user is redirected to callback url provided. Its your Callback URL for your application basically you have completed the step number 4 of Protocol Flow

Comment: I have set the call back url like this  in the routes config file `'loginredirect' => 'afterAuthentication'` any idea why is this not working?

Comment: Thanks, I solved the issue. google+ and contacts api needs to be enabled too.